# WPF C# MVVM DataGrid inside another DataGrid Binding doesn't work (SelectedItem)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, devexpress

I have a datagrid, inside of which there is another datagrid. There are also buttons for adding and deleting rows in the second (internal) table. The add button works fine, but the delete button does not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwxIA.png)

ViewModel of this page

```
    public class VM_Designers: BindableBase
    {
        private User _selectedUser;
        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get => _selectedUser;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedUser, value, nameof(SelectedUser));
        }
    
    
        private Users _users = new Users();
        public Users Users 
        {
            get => _users;
            set => SetProperty(ref _users, value, nameof(Users)); 
        }
        public ICommand Add_User => new RelayCommand(() => Users.Users_Add());
    public ICommand Remove_User => new RelayCommand(() => Users.Users_Remove(SelectedUser));
    public ICommand Edit_Mode => new RelayCommand(() => ReadOnly = !ReadOnly);
    public ICommand Save_Configuration => new RelayCommand(() => /*Save*/ ReadOnly = ReadOnly);
    
    public VM_Designers()
    {
        try
        {
            SelectedUser = Users._Users[0];
        }
        catch
        {
            SelectedUser = null;
        }
    }
```

Class  Users

```
    private ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public ObservableCollection<User> _Users
    {
        get => _users;
        set => SetProperty(ref _users, value, nameof(_Users));
    }
    
    public void Users_Add() => _Users.Add(new User());
    
    public void Users_Remove(User user) => _Users.Remove(user);
    
    public Users()
    {
        Users_Load();
    }
    
    private void Users_Load()
    {
        //JSON load 
    }
```

Class User where binding to selectedItem does not work

```
     private string _name;
     public string Name
     {
         get => _name;
         set => SetProperty(ref _name, value, nameof(Name));
     }
    
     private ObservableCollection<Account> _accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();
     public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts
     {
         get => _accounts;
         set => SetProperty(ref _accounts, value, nameof(Accounts));
     }
    
     private Account _selected_Account;
     public Account Selected_Account
     {
         get => _selected_Account;
         set
         {
             SetProperty(ref _selected_Account, value, nameof(Selected_Account));
             Console.WriteLine(value.Comment);
         }
     }
    
     public ICommand Account_Add => new RelayCommand(() => Accounts.Add(new Account()));
     public ICommand Account_Remove => new RelayCommand(() =>
     {
         try
         {
             //Console.WriteLine(Selected_Account.Comment);
             Accounts.Remove(Selected_Account);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
     });
```

Class Account

```
    public class Account: BindableBase
    {
        private string _login;
        public string Login { get => _login; set => SetProperty(ref _login, value, nameof(Login)); }

        private string _password;
        public string Password { get => _password; set => SetProperty(ref _password, value, nameof(Password)); }

        private string _comment;
        public string Comment { get => _comment; set => SetProperty(ref _comment, value, nameof(Comment)); }
    }
```

I also use DevExpressMVVM library

I don’t know how to correctly create such table structures, but I got something like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users._Users}" Name="MainGrid"
        HeadersVisibility="None"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" CanUserAddRows="False"
        Background="#05F0F0F0" Margin="15"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        RowBackground="Transparent">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="600" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_Account}" CanUserAddRows="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" Background="#05F0F0F0">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Width="600" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Login}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Comment}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Content="+" Width="20" Height="20" Command="{Binding Account_Add}" Margin="0,5,0,10"/>
                            <Button Content="-" Width="20" Height="20" Command="{Binding Account_Remove}" Margin="0,5,0,10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

At the beginning of the document I used an anchor to ViewModel

```
     <Page.DataContext>
         <viewmodel:VM_Designers/>
     </Page.DataContext>
```

I tried to monitor the current table values online and realized that the data is not always entered correctly into an instance of the Account class either. I can’t understand the reason, because binding and deleting cells of the main table works correctly.

Comment: Is the `Account_Remove` command invoked as expected? What's the value of `Selected_Account` if you set a breakpoint in the code and debug?